# Get values from a column having comma separated values using Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am working in a web based application in which i am using lots of Linq query to fetch the data. I am stuck in one issue were in i need to get the rows from a column which has a comma separated values  in it. I have a screen shot below :

[image: Table]

As you can see that in the above screen shot we have 5 columns. I need data such that in the network column. For eg:
Network column first row has CMT, second row also has CMT and other rows also has CMT respectively.
But in the 8th row there is no CMT.
I need the rows only from networks having CMT values in it. Can anybody help me to write a Linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>
{
    new {userid="SIMONE", networks = "CMT,MTT,MVV"},
    new {userid="CURTINK", networks = "MTR,NAN,NOG"},
    new {userid="JAMESL", networks = "CMT,LOGO,CMDY"},
    new {userid="BONDINEG", networks = "TVL,TVLC,NKTN"}
};
var users = String.Join(",", list.Where(d => d.networks.Contains("CMT"))
                                 .Select(u => u.userid));
```

Comment: Hi JohnyL, Thanks a lot for your quick response. This worked for me. Now i get list of users. Now i only need is comma separated values of UserIds

Comment: Updated answer.